# How to give one space between number in json string java?

Tags: java, json, regex, string, gson

In my below code, I am making a json string using gson:

```
private String generateData(Map<String, Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>> nodeTable, int i) {
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

    Set<Integer> pp = nodeTable.get("TEXTER").get(i);
    Set<Integer> sp = nodeTable.get("PETER").get(i);

    // my above pp and sp variables shows correct values with one space between numbers.

    jsonObject.addProperty("description", "Hello. World");
    jsonObject.add("data1", gson.toJsonTree(pp));
    jsonObject.add("data2", gson.toJsonTree(sp));

    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());

    return jsonObject.toString();
}
```

When I get my json string, I get it like this. As you can see after comma everything is next to each other without any spaces. I don't want like that.

```
{"description":"Hello. World.","data1":[0,273,546,819,1092,559],"data2":[816,1644,1368,276]}
```

I want to have one space between numbers in data1 and data2 variable as shown below:

```
{"description":"Hello. World.","data1":[0, 273, 546, 819, 1092, 559],"data2":[816, 1644, 1368, 276]}
```

Is this possible to do by any chance using gson or some other way?

Comment: you are bound to the implementation of `toString` method from the library. Why do you like this differently ? for processing it doesn't matter

Comment: I am passing data1 and data2 to my python program and they are expecting it to have spaces in between.. Easiest way I can think of changing is this code instead of changing python code, bcoz then I need to change in all our servers which is not possible so thats why I want to change this code if possible bcoz we can deploy this code easily.

Comment: Bug ridden approach just to put spaces after commas for integers and if its a String, why are there numbers there? Think through.

Comment: It won't be string, it will always be integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems rather a cosmetic request with potential for bugs. Easiest way is probably using a regex:

```
jsonString = jsonString
    .replaceAll("(\\d),(\\d)", "$1, $2")
    .replaceAll("(\\d),(\\d)", "$1, $2")
```

The line above simply catches any digit + comma + digit sequence and adds a space between the two captured and restored digits. Since java catches matches only once, thus not allowing intersections, we're doing it two times here.

Alternative that is not so strict but doesn't require double replacing:

```
jsonString = jsonString.replaceAll(",(\\d)", ", $1")
```

The bug potential here is that this applies to the whole JSON string, not only encoded sets.

The right way™ would be to use a custom set formatter for GSON.

BTW, a map of maps cries for classes.

Comment: can you provide an example how regex will work in my case?

Comment: done. jsonString is the output of your jsonObject.toString()

Comment: It just add spaces after the first number. `{"description":"Hello. World","data1":[1, 2,3],"data2":[4, 5,6]}`

Comment: Illegal escape character issue at compile time in regex at update code as jsonString.replaceAll("(\\d),(\\d)", "$1, $2")

Comment: I am still getting space only after the first number. After that it doesn't work.  This is what it prints out `{"description":"Hello. World","data1":[1, 2,3],"data2":[4, 5,6]}`

Comment: Ah, right. I tested with bigger numbers. Apply the replaceAll two times so that intersecting matches are considered. Updating answer right away.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get space by using following methods like below

```
For 1:
jsonObject.add("data1", gson.toJsonTree(addSpaces(pp)));
jsonObject.add("data2", gson.toJsonTree(addSpaces(sp)))

For 2: 
String string = addSpaceByRegEx(jsonObject.toString());
```

Add following methods in you class :

```
//1. if you need String value based spaces in json string
public Set<String> addSpaces(Set<Integer> integers) {
    Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>();
    for (Integer i : integers) {
        strings.add(i.toString() + " ");
    }
    return strings;
}

//2. if you need space as in integer value in json string as your example
//This method add space by using regex 
//Tested for String s = "{'description':'Hello. World.','data1':[0,273,546,819,1092,559],'data2':[816,1644,1368,276]}";
//In you example just replace following line
//System.out.println(jsonObject.toString()); by System.out.println(addSpaceByRegEx(jsonObject.toString()));
//See result, i think it work
public String addSpaceByRegEx(String jsonString) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",[0-9]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jsonString);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int prevIndex = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        int startIndex = matcher.start();
        int endIndex = matcher.end();
        sb.append(jsonString.substring(prevIndex, startIndex + 1)).append(" ").append(jsonString.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex));
        prevIndex = endIndex;
    }
    sb.append(jsonString.substring(prevIndex, jsonString.length()));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: It prints like this `{"description":"Hello. World","data1":["2 ","1 ","3 "],"data2":["4 ","6 ","5 "]}` As you can see in my question - I don't have double quotes string numbers in data1 and data2.

Comment: Ok i need few minute.

Comment: Thanks it works almost. But when i run it prints out like this `{"description":"Hello. World","data1":[1 ,2 ,3],"data2":[4 ,5 ,6]}`. I was looking for something like this `1, 2, 3` in data1 and `4, 5, 6` in data2. In your output it prints comma before a number. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Ok i need few minute i will correct it as your requirement.

Comment: I update code as your requirement if works please accept.

Comment: Sorry, but this is ridiculously overcomplicated

Comment: Just use jsonString .replaceAll("(\\d),(\\d)", "$1, $2");